# How to index to a 3-D dynamic array?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, dynamic

I created a 3-d dynamic array in this way:

```
double *A = (double *)malloc(M * N * N * sizeof(int));
```

This is the equivalent of the static matrix:

```
double A[M][N][N];
```

I want to refer to each index implementing the static behavior:

```
for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {

            for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {

                    for(k = 0; k < M; k++) {

                        if (i!=j)
                            A[k][j][i] = (y[j]*gain[k][i])/gain[k][j];
                        else
                            A[k][j][i] = 0;

                            printf("%f ", A[k][j][i]);
                    }

            }
}
```

So I tried this:

```
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {       //matrix A

            for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {

                    for(k = 0; k < M; k++) {

                        if (i!=j)
                            *(A + k*N + j + i) = (*(y+j) * *((gain+k*N)+i)) / *((gain+k*N)+j);
                        else
                            *(A + k*N + j + i) = 0;

                            printf("%f ", *(A + k*N + j + i));
                    }

            }
}
```

Is this the right syntax?

Comment: `double (*A)[N][N] = malloc(M * sizeof *A);` would be the equivalent to `double A[M][N][N];`. Then you can use it like `A[k][j][i]`.

Comment: Nope. You can tell because `A[k][1][0]` and `A[k][0][1]` refer to the same place.

Comment: If you wanna go with the `double *A`, the correct indexing should be `A[k*N*N + j*N + i]` to simulate a the 3d indexing of `A[k][j][i]`.

Comment: Your memory allocation is allocating space for integers, not `double`. That’s a problem.

Comment: @mch thats a cool trick, will it allocate   each of [N][N] elements? Didn't know you can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replacement for the static `double A[M][N][N]` with dynamic version is

`double *A = (double *)malloc(M * N * N * sizeof(double))` with no `sizeof(int)`.

The use of the static `A[k][j][i]` would be replaced in the dynamic allocation case with

`A[k * (N * N) + j * N + i]`.

Expanding the answer with some example code:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  int a5x3x2[5][3][2] = {{{4, 6}, {4, 6}, {4, 6}},
                         {{4, 6}, {4, 6}, {4, 6}},
                         {{4, 6}, {4, 6}, {4, 6}},
                         {{4, 6}, {4, 6}, {4, 6}},
                         {{4, 6}, {4, 6}, {4, 6}}};
  int a2x3x5[2][3][5] = {{{7, 8, 9, 10, 11}, {7, 8, 9, 10, 11}, {7, 8, 9, 10, 11}},
                         {{7, 8, 9, 10, 11}, {7, 8, 9, 10, 11}, {7, 8, 9, 10, 11}}};

  int const x = 1;
  int const y = 1;
  int const z = 1;

  a5x3x2[x][y][z] = 42;
  int *p = &a5x3x2[0][0][0];
  assert(p[x * (3 * 2) + y * (2) + z] == 42);

  a2x3x5[x][y][z] = 24;
  p = &a2x3x5[0][0][0];
  assert(p[x * (3 * 5) + y * (5) + z] == 24);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And here is a full 3D example showing the generic logic:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  enum { Xsize = 3, Ysize = 5, Zsize = 7 };
  double static3D[Zsize][Ysize][Xsize];
  double* dynamic3D = (double*)malloc(Zsize * Ysize * Xsize * sizeof(double));
  for (int z = 0; z < Zsize; ++z)
    for (int y = 0; y < Ysize; ++y)
      for (int x = 0; x < Xsize; ++x)
        static3D[z][y][x] = dynamic3D[z * (Ysize * Xsize) + y * Xsize + x] =
            (x + 1) * (y + 1) * (z + 1);
  assert(memcmp(static3D, dynamic3D, sizeof(static3D)) == 0);
  free(dynamic3D);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```